# curl: how to specify target hostname for https request

Tags: ssl, curl, sni

I have a `x.example` which serves traffic for both `a.example` and `b.example`.
`x.example` has certificates for both `a.example` and `b.example`. The DNS for `a.example` and `b.example` is not yet set up.

If I add an `/etc/hosts` entry for `a.example` pointing to `x.example`'s ip and run `curl -XGET https://a.example`, I get a 200.

However if I run `curl --header 'Host: a.example' https://x.example`, I get:

> curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target
>   host name x.example

I would think it would use a.example as the host. Maybe I'm not understanding how SNI/TLS works.

Because `a.example` is an HTTP header the TLS handshake doesn't have access to it yet? But the URL itself it does have access to?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Indeed SNI in TLS does not work like that. SNI, as everything related to TLS, happens before any kind of HTTP traffic, hence the `Host` header is not taken into account at that step (but will be useful later on for the webserver to know which host you are connecting too).

So to enable SNI you need a specific switch in your HTTP client to tell it to send the appropriate TLS extension during the handshake with the hostname value you need.

In case of `curl`, you need at least version 7.18.1 (based on https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html) and then it seems to automatically use the value provided in the `Host` header. It alo depends on which OpenSSL (or equivalent library on your platform) version it is linked to.

See point 1.10 of https://curl.haxx.se/docs/knownbugs.html that speaks about a bug but explains what happens:

> When given a URL with a trailing dot for the host name part: "https://example.com./", libcurl will strip off the dot and use the name without a dot internally and send it dot-less in HTTP Host: headers and in the TLS SNI field.

The `--connect-to` option could also be useful in your case. Or `--resolve` as a substitute to `/etc/hosts`, see https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2015-01/0042.html for am example, or https://makandracards.com/makandra/1613-make-an-http-request-to-a-machine-but-fake-the-hostname
You can add `--verbose` in all cases to see in more details what is happening. See this example: https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/693/curious-case-of-curl-ssl-tls-sni-http-host-header ; you will also see there how to test directly with `openssl`.

If you have `a.example` in your `/etc/hosts` you should just run curl with `https://a.example/` and it should take care of the `Host` header and hence SNI (or use `--resolve` instead)

So to answer your question directly, replace

```
curl --header 'Host: a.example' https://x.example
```

with

```
curl --connect-to a.example:443:x.example:443 https://a.example
```

and it should work perfectly.

Comment: In curl version 7.58.0, it doesn't, and the manpage says it doesn't: `It does NOT affect the hostname/port that is used for TLS/SSL (e.g. SNI, certificate verification)`.

Comment: For my use case the --connect-to parameter was perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

The selected answer helped me find the answer, even though it does not **contain** the answer. The answer in the mail/archive link Patrick Mevzek provided has the **wrong** port number. So even following that answer will cause it to continue to fail.

I used [this container](https://github.com/mendhak/docker-http-https-echo) to run a debugging server to inspect the requests. I highly suggest anyone debugging this kind of issue do the same.

Here is how to address the OP's question.

```
# Instead of this:
# curl --header 'Host: a.example'        https://x.example

# Do:
  host=a.example
  target=x.example

  ip=$(dig +short $target | head -n1)
  curl -sv   --resolve $host:443:$ip https://$host
```

If you want to ignore bad certificates matches, use `-svk` instead of `-sv`

```
curl -svk --resolve $host:443:$ip https://$host
```

**Note**: Since you are using https, you must use `443` in the `--resolve` argument instead of `80` as was stated on the [mail/archive](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2015-01/0042.html)

Comment: Very useful on a Mac as Catalina no longer seems to let you manually configure your hosts file.

Comment: instead `  ip=$(dig +short x.example | head -n1)`
use `  ip=$(dig +short "$target" | head -n1)`

Comment: Doh! Corrected. Thank you, @Rax. (I miss your [roast beef sandwiches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rax_Roast_Beef). Arby's is inferior.)

Comment: @SamCritchley I don't think that's correct. /etc/hosts still works, but you  need the right context. And it isn't the OS that should support it or not, but the apps/browser. Safari, for example, sends a https binding dns request and if the gets an answer, it ignores /etc/hosts.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @Lethargos, sorry about that.

Comment: Firefox still works, for instance :) I'm not sure how long. You'd need to have your own DNS server to be able to test domains which have https binding :)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar need. Didn't have sudo access to update hosts file.

I use *resolve* parameter and also added the DNS host name as a *header* parameter.

```
--resolve <dns name>:<port>:<ip addr>

curl --request POST --resolve dns_name:443:a.b.c.d 'https://dns_name/x/y' --header 'Host: dns_name' ....
```

Cheers..