# SSL: certificate subject name (192.168.104.119) does not match target host name '192.168.104.119'

Tags: linux, git, certificate, self-signed

I'm trying to access my gitlab's repositories using 'git clone [https://192.168.104.119/sibon/testgit.git'](https://192.168.104.119/sibon/testgit.git%27),  but I'm getting this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://192.168.104.119/sibon/testgit.git/': SSL: certificate subject name (192.168.104.119) does not match target host name '192.168.104.119'
```

Before 'git clone', I had placed the self-signed certificate '192.168.104.119.pem' in /home/sibon/git-certs/, and had run the below command：

```
git config --global http.sslCAInfo /home/sibon/git-certs/192.168.104.119.pem
```

In addition, when I run "curl https://192.168.104.119/sibon/testgit.git --cacert /home/sibon/git-certs/192.168.104.119.pem", it successed.

the concent of 192.168.104.119.pem is below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYdCO.jpg)

So, I want to know, in "fatal: unable to access 'https://192.168.104.119/sibon/testgit.git/': SSL: certificate subject name (192.168.104.119) does not match target host name '192.168.104.119'", the subject name have been samed with the target host name, why the error occured。

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve the error "certificate subject name does not match target host name"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377036/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-certificate-subject-name-does-not-match-target-host)

Comment: We also need to know what the subjectAltName fields contain, because CN is no longer used for validating certificates.